# Delete double entries in two lists in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, list, duplicates

I have 2 lists:

```
Dim xList As New List(Of Integer)
Dim yList As New List(Of Integer)
```

I want to delete duplicate entries like in the following table:
[image]

My idea was to define two separate indexes to iterate for every point over all entries. However, the lists contain a lot of data points (10^6) so the CPU usage is way too high. Is it better to work with arrays? Can you give me a hint how I could do this?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Why don't you use a `List(Of Drawing.Point)`? Then it was simple as `pointList = pointList.Distinct().ToList()`. Or use a `HashSet(Of Point)` to avoid duplicates in the first place.

Comment: What does the data represent and where did it come from? As suggested above, it would be better to use a single list of a composite type if possible. If data at the same index belongs together then it should be stored together.